# san-angeles project

Tags: vs-android

i was trying to run the san-angeles example for vs-android ...

i have winxpsp3 and vs 2010 installed on my machine ..

these are the steps for installation ... my question is :
in this step .... :
**NDK Setup**
Download the NDK from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html
Unzip it somewhere, and note the root directory.
You need to set an environment variable named ANDROID_NDK_ROOT which points to this directory. This can be done from the command line:

> setx ANDROID_NDK_ROOT c:\android-ndk-r6

- How to achieve the above line (  setx ANDROID_NDK_ROOT c:\android-ndk-r6 ) ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got it :

just goto my computer (right-click) navigate to properties and then (Advanced Tab) choose 
Enviroment Vairiables => system variable => New => Write down (ANDROID_NDK_ROOT) THEN Value 
(c:\android-ndk-r7) if you the version is r7 ....

it depends on your NDK version .... and same is for Java - Ant - SDK

- JAVA_HOME => Java Dir
- ANT_HOME => Apache Ant Dir